Are textbook acoustic and optical phonons excitations of a free vector bosonic quantum field?
Consider a free vector bosonic quantum field characterized by the Hamiltonian
$$H = h_0 + \sum_\sigma \int \frac{d\vec{k}}{(2\pi)^3} \omega_\sigma(\vec{k})[a^\dagger_\sigma(\vec{k})a_\sigma(\vec{k})]$$
where $\sigma$ corresponds to a notion of polarization, $\vec{k}$ to a notion of momentum, and $h_0$ is the renormalized zero-point energy.
Are phonons excitations of this free vector quantum field? Are acoustic and optical phonons accounted for by specifying the asymptotic behavior of the dispersion relation? I.e.,
$$\text{if $\vec{k}$ small, then } \omega_\sigma(\vec{k})^2 \sim k^2 \text{ (acoustic)},$$
$$\text{if $\vec{k}$ large, then } \omega_\sigma(\vec{k})^2 \sim m^2 + k^2 \text{ (optical)}.$$
I am looking for answer that works in the framework of quantum field theory.
Note: I am using "quantum field" in the loose sense of an operator-valued field. Not the strict sense of an operator-valued field that transforms under a finite-dimensional irreducible representation of the (universal cover of the) Poincaré group.

The point is that your sum is over all possible $\vec{k}$. In a real lattice the sum takes place only on some values of $\vec{k}$, the ones which account for the symmetries of the lattice. Taking this specification into account, I think that your idea makes sense.
